# Set width of a ggplot (plotting area) to a fixed value

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have to barplots with labels (Variable `item`) on the y-axis that differ in their length.
As the length of the labels is different the plotting area (the area with the light-gray background) is smaller in one plot than in the other. How can I set a fixed value for the plot width, so that both plots look identical (aside from the data of course)?

```r
dat <- tibble(item=c("A very long item name with many words",
                     "Another extremely long item name with many words",
                     "Short item name",
                     "Short item name two"),
              y = c(2, 3, 5, 2),
              split = c(1, 1, 0, 0))

# Short item names
dat %>%
  filter(split == 0) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = item, y = y)) +
    geom_col() +
    coord_flip()

# Long item names
dat %>%
  filter(split == 1) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = item, y = y)) +
  geom_col() +
  coord_flip()
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few different ways to do this, but they all involve some trade-offs. Perhaps the simplest is to fix the aspect ratio of the panel using `theme(aspect.ratio = xx)`:

```r
# Short item names
dat %>%
  filter(split == 0) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = item, y = y)) +
  geom_col() +
  coord_flip() +
  theme(aspect.ratio = 2)
```

[image]

```r
# Long item names
dat %>%
  filter(split == 1) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = item, y = y)) +
  geom_col() +
  coord_flip() +
  theme(aspect.ratio = 2)
```

[image]

Provided your plot dimensions, title and x axis labels are the same, then this will give you an identical plotting panel in each plot. The downside is that the panels will be out of alignment on the page. Fixing this is less straightforward, but is possible by faking the axis labels inside a blank plot and stitching this onto your main plot panel using `patchwork`

```r
library(patchwork)

short_plot <- dat %>%
  filter(split == 0) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = item, y = y)) +
  geom_col() +
  coord_flip() +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank())

short_labs <- dat %>%
  filter(split == 0) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = item)) +
  geom_text(aes(y = 1, label = item), hjust = 1, size = 3,
            check_overlap = TRUE) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 1)) +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_void() +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(angle = 90, size = 12))

short_labs + short_plot
```

[image]

```r
long_plot <- dat %>%
  filter(split == 1) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = item, y = y)) +
  geom_col() +
  coord_flip() +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank())

long_labs <- dat %>%
  filter(split == 1) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = item)) +
  geom_text(aes(y = 1, label = item), hjust = 1, size = 3, 
            check_overlap = TRUE) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 1)) +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_void() +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(angle = 90, size = 12))

long_labs + long_plot
```

[image]

Although this is more involved, it gives you full control of the panel size and alignment whatever the axis labels are.